# Slow Transition Between Activities android

Tags: java, android, android-activity, runtime, surfaceview

I have an android activity with a surfaceview which displays the preview of the camera to the user. When I swipe left on this activity the following code is executed and a new activity is launched with an animation :

```
Intent I = new Intent(CameraScreen.this,ViewScreen.class);
            startActivity(I);
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fadein3, R.anim.fadeout3);
```

The problem with this is that the below onPause method is executed which causes the display to first go dark since the camera preview is stopped and the overall transition is very laggy. Now, ideally in the future I am going to solve this by converting by activities to fragments and using ViewPager. The problem is I need to present this prototype soon and I need a temporary solution to overcome this delay and laggy experience, which can be implemented quickly and doesn't require converting the activities to fragments. I was thinking of applying a delay before the intent is launched however, I'm not sure how to do this or if it would solve the issue.

```
 @Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if (mCamera != null) {
        mCamera.stopPreview();
        mCamera.setPreviewCallback(null);
        mCameraView.getHolder().removeCallback(mCameraView);
        mCamera.release();
        mCamera = null;
        FrameLayout camera_view = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.camera_view);
        camera_view.removeAllViews();
    }
}
```

Comment: did you end up finding a solution?